# PTR Record for Mail Server

Tags: email, ptr-record

Our email server is setup for Domain POP/ Mail Bagging with our ISP for receiving only. Our MX Record resolves to our ISP mail host address. We have 2 IP addresses (redundancy purpose), 1 from our mail hosting ISP(ISP1) and the other from a different ISP.

Domain Name: abc.com.au

MX record points to: mailgate.ISP1.com.au

Question is can i setup PTR record for both IP addresses pointing to our domain (abc.com.au)?

Comment: Your existing MX record doesn't point to mailgate.isp1.com.au, it points to an IP address. [You need to fix this first](http://serverfault.com/a/663122/126632) as it will prevent you from receiving mail from some senders. Not to mention isp1.com.au's DNS servers seem to be broken anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could but you should have different names for the two endpoints and corresponding IN PTR records for each.

The value of an IN PTR record can be anything, and so having two of them point to the same fqdn is not a problem.

You should address the other brokenness in your MX records first.